# How can I make a blurred area appear around a button without using outline?

Tags: html, css

I have a styled button and I would like to have an outline show around it.  I tried outline but it does not follow the curves of the border-radius of my button. Is there some other way I can do this.

Note the button is in a table of many other buttons. It's important that the table grid spacing is the same so whatever solution must take this into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `:after` pseudo-selector to create a surrounding box which has it's own border properties (radius, color, width etc). I've notched something up below:

```
.button{
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: relative
    margin: 4px;
}
.button:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    left: -4px;
    right: -4px;
    bottom: -4px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
}
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/ko499adr/1/

Comment: Usually because no code (of attempted to solve the problem) was given. Users like to see people try to answer their own questions first.

Comment: Well actually I did try to solve it with outline but it didn't work. So not sure what else I couild have done :-(

Comment: Include the CSS that you've tried so developers can see what DIDN'T work. You'll come across it a lot on StackOverflow. Glad I could help.